# Django celery - asyncio - daemonic process are not allowed to have children

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I can see similar questions have been asked before but those are running multi processors and not executors. Therefore I am unsure how to fix this.

the GitHub issue also say its resolved in 4.1 https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1709

I am using

```
celery==4.1.1
django-celery==3.2.1
django-celery-beat==1.0.1
django-celery-results==1.0.1
```

My script as as follows, ive tried to cut it down to show relevant code only.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def snmp_get(ip, oid, snmp_user, snmp_auth, snmp_priv):
    results=[]
    snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = yield from getCmd(
                            ...
                        )
    ...
        for varBind in varBinds:
            results.append(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    return results

def create_link_data_record(link_data):
    obj = LinkData.objects.create(
        ...
    )
    return 'data polled for {} record {} created'.format(link_data.hostname, obj.id)


async def retrieve_data(link, loop):
    from  concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)

    poll_interval = 60
    results = []
    # credentials:
    ...
    print('polling data for {} on {}'.format(hostname,link_mgmt_ip))

    # create link data obj
    link_data = LinkDataObj()
    ...

    # first poll for speeds
    download_speed_data_poll1 = await snmp_get(link_mgmt_ip, down_speed_oid % link_index ,snmp_user, snmp_auth, snmp_priv)
    download_speed_data_poll1 = await snmp_get(link_mgmt_ip, down_speed_oid % link_index ,snmp_user, snmp_auth, snmp_priv)

    # check we were able to poll
    if 'timeout' in str(get_snmp_value(download_speed_data_poll1)).lower():
        return 'timeout trying to poll {} - {}'.format(hostname ,link_mgmt_ip)
    upload_speed_data_poll1 = await snmp_get(link_mgmt_ip, up_speed_oid % link_index, snmp_user, snmp_auth, snmp_priv) 

    # wait for poll interval
    await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

    # second poll for speeds
    download_speed_data_poll2 = await snmp_get(link_mgmt_ip, down_speed_oid % link_index, snmp_user, snmp_auth, snmp_priv)
    upload_speed_data_poll2 = await snmp_get(link_mgmt_ip, up_speed_oid % link_index, snmp_user, snmp_auth, snmp_priv)    

    # create deltas for speed
    down_delta = int(get_snmp_value(download_speed_data_poll2)) - int(get_snmp_value(download_speed_data_poll1))
    up_delta = int(get_snmp_value(upload_speed_data_poll2)) - int(get_snmp_value(upload_speed_data_poll1)) 
    ...
    results.append(await loop.run_in_executor(executor, create_link_data_record, link_data))
    return results


def get_link_data():  
    link_data = LinkTargets.objects.all() 
    # create loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed():
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    # create tasks 
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(retrieve_data(link, loop)) for link in link_data]
    if tasks:
        start = time.time()  
        done, pending = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
        loop.close()
```

the error below which references the run_in_executor code

```
[2018-05-24 14:13:00,840: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task exception was never retrieved
    future: <Task finished coro=<retrieve_data() done, defined at /itapp/itapp/monitoring/jobs/link_monitoring.py:130> exception=AssertionError('daemonic processes are not allowed to have children',)>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/itapp/itapp/monitoring/jobs/link_monitoring.py", line 209, in retrieve_data
        link_data.last_change = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, timestamp, (link_data.link_target_id, link_data.service_status))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 639, in run_in_executor
        return futures.wrap_future(executor.submit(func, *args), loop=self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 466, in submit
        self._start_queue_management_thread()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 427, in _start_queue_management_thread
        self._adjust_process_count()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 446, in _adjust_process_count
        p.start()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 103, in start
        'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
    AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `Celery 5-devel`

```
pip install git+https://github.com/celery/celery@5.0-devel
```

As per below issue

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3884

> Celery 5.0 will support asyncio. We currently do not support it.

And then there is also below SO thread on same

[How to combine Celery with asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio)

Comment: every time I install 5.0 pip is still showing 4.0.2?
root@955cd9001b9a:# pip install git+https://github.com/celery/celery@5.0-devel
Collecting git+https://github.com/celery/celery@5.0-devel
  Cloning https://github.com/celery/celery (to revision 5.0-devel) to
...
Successfully built celery
Installing collected packages: celery
Successfully installed celery-4.0.2

Comment: so 5.0 will not install? or it installs but is named 4.0.2?
when I try and run I get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amqp.types'

Comment: It's a dev branch and I am not sure how close or how far is it from the 5.0 milestone. Only a commiter could tell

Comment: are there any alternates you know of where I can use asycnio?